# What is meant by server jobs in azure devops pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

I got the following definition from Microsoft docs *"A server job does not require an agent or any target computers"*. My question is without any target computers or agent, how it will run?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is without any target computers or agent, how it will run?

It is ran by the Azure Devops Pipeline directly. It will be easier for you to understand if you check the usement of the agentless tasks suppoerted.

Let's take the "Delay" task for example, when this task started, it will keep the parent Agentless job waiting for several minutes. This can totally be done by the pipeline itself, there's no need to ask for an agent to do it.

Check other few agentless task and you will notice the same situation. Generally speaking, all the jobs are orchestrated and executed by Azure DevOps Pipeline but some(most) of them need also agents support which makes them Agent Jobs.

Comment: Is it clear now how the angenless jobs work? You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or feel free to tell if the problem is still confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can find another definition [Types of jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#types-of-jobs):

> Server jobs run on the Azure DevOps Server

[Server Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#server-jobs)

> Tasks in a server job are orchestrated by and executed on the server
>   (Azure Pipelines or TFS)

So this job will be ran directly on Azure DevOps Server/Team Foundation Server

Not so many types of tasks available on this stage by default:

[image]